# How do I ignore punctuation marks and whitespace in java?

Tags: java, palindrome, punctuation

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please input a word: ");
        String Line = keyboard.nextLine();
        boolean x = isReverse(Line);
        System.out.print("It is " + x + " that this word is a palindrome.");
    }
    public static boolean isReverse(String Line) {
        int length = Line.length();
        boolean x = true;
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (Line.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                s += Line.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (Line.charAt(i) != Line.charAt(length - 1 -i)) {
                x = false;
            }
        }
        return x;   
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is make a program that takes a word or phrase as input and returns true or false depending on if it is a palindrome or not. In the program I am supposed to ignore whitespace and punctuation marks and make palindromes such as "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama." I think I have solved the whitespace problem, but can not figure out how to ignore all punctuation marks.

Comment: I am using scanner class I am wondering how I would change my code so that any phrase i input gets this done to it.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [a regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to remove all the non-word characters from your string: `\\W` represents non-word characters

```
String s = "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama.";
String lettersOnly = s.replaceAll("[\\W]", "");
System.out.println("lettersOnly = " + lettersOnly);
```

outputs:

> lettersOnly = AmanaplanacanalPanama

If you want to reduce the length of your code, you can also use [`StringBuilder#reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) to reverse the string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please input a word: ");
    String line = keyboard.nextLine();

    String cleanLine = line.replaceAll("[\\W]", "");
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(cleanLine).reverse().toString();
    boolean isPalindrome = cleanLine.equals(reverse);

    System.out.print("It is " + isPalindrome + " that this word is a palindrome.");
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need to stick to the loop, you can simply check in your loop if the characters are letters:

```
public static boolean isReverse(String Line) {
    int length = Line.length();
    boolean x = true;
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if ((Line.charAt(i) >= 'a' && Line.charAt(i) <= 'z')
          || (Line.charAt(i) >= 'A' && Line.charAt(i) <= 'Z')) {
            s += Line.charAt(i);
        }
    }
```

Note: you will have an issue with the case (`A` != `a`) - an easy fix is to first put all characters in lower case with `String lowerCase = Line.toLowerCase();`.

Comment: I am using scanner class I am wondering how I would change my code so that any phrase i input gets this done to it.

Comment: @user1730357 `boolean x = isReverse(Line.replaceAll("[\\W]", ""));` instead of `boolean x = isReverse(Line);`.

Comment: @user1730357 I have added a shorter and easier version if that helps you.

Comment: I added that to the boolean x but it still won't work. Also don't quite know what the s totally does as i asked someone else and they said to use the other for loop.

Comment: @user1730357 The `s` in my initial example is your `Line`.

Comment: I am only in my second semester of java so what you just typed doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: @user1730357 In your code, you simply need to replace `boolean x = isReverse(Line);` by `boolean x = isReverse(Line.replaceAll("[\\W]", ""));` - that will replace all the non-word characters of the input before it is passed to your `isReverse` method. The second example I gave simply relies on the available built-in methods to do the same thing in less lines of code (which generally means less bugs).

Comment: @user1730357 I have added an additional example that matches your code more closely.

Comment: I did this in the main method, but it does not seem to work. Also do i even need my first for loop?

Comment: @user1730357 The first loop removes the punctuation, spaces and so on. So yes you need it. I suggest you run your code in a debugger step by step to better understand what each line does.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll take a look at my code now and try what you said.

Answer (score 1):

The `StringUtils` class in [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) has some methods that may be handy including `deleteWhitespace()` and `difference()`.  Passing your string to `difference()` along with a string of all punctuation characters that you want to remove would return a punctuation free string.